# How to install the latest Renderman add on for the latest Blender

Tags: renderman-render-engine

I am new to Renderman as well as to Blender. First I have installed the free version of the Renderman 24. Then I have installed the latest Blender 2.93.1. Then I downloaded the zip folder from https://github.com/prman-pixar/RenderManForBlender. It downloaded the master version from GitHub. Then I opened Blender and then Edit -> Preferences -> Install and choose the downloaded zip file. But I am getting, "importError: DLL load failed while importing _oslquery: The specified module could not be found. I tried to download the main version also from GitHub. But got same error.

Comment: Some addons cannot be installed with the blender internal installer. However, a DLL error would probably not be caused by that…

Comment: Renderman 24 is supported in Blender 2.92